# TS Node - Must use import to load ES Module: server/src/index.ts

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node-dev

I am trying to start a typescript node project and I've installed some dependencies (typescript, eslint, mongoose and graphql). However, when I run

```
ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only src/index.ts
```

I get the error

```
Must use import to load ES Module: server/src/index.ts
```

My `index.ts` file is simply:

```
console.log('Hello world!');
```

and my `tsconfig.json` file is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./build",
    "lib": ["ES2021", "ESNext.AsyncIterable"],
    "target": "ES2021",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "strict": true 
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```

I have set `type` to `module` in `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this config, may fix your problem:

```
"module": "commonjs"
```

But check the complete discuss about this problem in ts-node-dev github https://github.com/wclr/ts-node-dev/issues/265

There another options to try.